# Meteor-Jade and object literals?

Tags: meteor, pug

I use Jade in Meteor and want to set a placeholder in `EasySearch.Input` like this:

```
+EasySearch.Input(index=objects_index attributes={placeholder: 'sample'})
```

At least the documentation suggests this way:

> **attributes**: Object containing input attributes (e.g. { placeholder: "Search..." })

I tried this in a naive way, and client crashed:

```
 While processing files with mquandalle:jade (for target web.browser):
 client/objlist.jade: Jade syntax error: Expected IDENTIFIER
 ...ch.Input attributes=('placeholder': 'samp...
                    ^
 client/objlist.jade: Jade syntax error: Cannot read property 'head' of undefined
```

I tried a solution from github issues:

```
+EasySearch.Input(attributes="{{{placeholder: 'sample'}}}" index=objects_index)
```

Still this didn't work.

> html.js:232 Uncaught Error: Illegal HTML attribute name: 0

Should I publish a variable or make another helper for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape this with a bang and tildes:

```
attributes!= `{placeholder: 'sample'}`
```

This tells pug to use an unescaped literal expression.